# $2\times2$ matrix that represents divergence or curl of the space?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vector-fields, curl

i can't understand the question (d) and (e). for example, curl is a vector but as i know the matrices in the problem is not vectors.

[image: this is a problem]

Comment: Welcome to M.SE. It would be helpful for potential helpers if you'd type in the question. See the MathJax Tutorial in case you need help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is it from Engineering Mathematics 1 course mid-term project?

I don't know how to properly describe d), but for e) I think it means that we just have to choose matrix which rotates vector (i.e acting on vector it rotates it about origin) since curl of a vector is a measure of how much vector wants to be rotated about an axis.

Comment: For d) is like choosing matrix which changes only magnitude of vector since the divergence of a vector field simply measures how much the flow is expanding at a given point.